# Using a control as input for a method

Tags: c#, methods, input

Im trying to create a method that will make all textboxes Enable property false. The method input will be the tab name, but something is not working

```
public void fechacampos(Control tab)
    {
        foreach (Control control in this.tab.Controls)
        {
            if (control is TextBox)
            {
                TextBox tb = control as TextBox;
                tb.Enabled = false;      
            }
        }
    }
```

Can someone help? Thanks!

Comment: What isn't working? Edit your query to reflect your expected behaviour and what you get instead.

Comment: Is this a WinForms question?

Comment: cant u have `TextBox` as parameter type?

Answer (score 0):

There might be other controls nested in the tab (e.g. Panels) with textboxes inside, so you will need to call your method recursively:

```
public void DisableTextBoxes(Control tab)
{
    foreach (Control control in tab.Controls)
    {
        if (control is TextBox)
        {
            TextBox tb = control as TextBox;
            tb.Enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (Control innerControl in control.Controls)
            {
                DisableTextBoxes(control);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also, the method's parameter is not a tab name, it's a control. If you want to start with a tab name, you will have to get the tab first:

```
var tabPage = tabControl.TabPages["tabPage1"];
DisableTextBoxes(tabPage);
```

Comment: Nice add to the code. I've found what were wrong in my code based on yours, its was the _this_ statement. Thanks!